# Correct use of "ein solcher, eine solche, ein solches"

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun

I have done quite an extensive reading on the internet to find out about the use of "solch-". By now I can say that I understand it quite well but I still don't understand why does the following example uses "ein solche" instead of "ein solch" or "ein solches"?

> Es ist einfach ein solche starkes Medium. [Reverso Context examples](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/ein+solche)

Comment: Weil Deine Quelle Schrott ist - die ersten 4 Beispiele sind alle falsch, weiter habe ich nicht geschaut. Deine eigenen Vorschläge dagegen sind richtig.

Comment: “I have done quite an extensive reading on the internet“. That's the problem of generation google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was alerted to the fact that your search [included the terms *ein+solche*](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/ein+solche). The exact terms give 62 results. I had assumed that the search would somehow average over multiple varieties but it doesn’t. Indeed, if you modify your search term to read [*eine+solche*](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/eine+solche) you get 21709 results and even the (possible but more constrained) search terms [*eine+solch*](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/eine+solch) which requires a following adjective returns 403 exact hits.

A few [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ein+solche%2Cein+solcher%2Cein+solches%2Ceine+solche&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cein%20solche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cein%20solcher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cein%20solches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceine%20solche%3B%2Cc0) serve to illustrate the prevalence of different forms, all showing that the combination of *ein solche* is practically not found aside from mistypings in German:

[image: Relative frequency of *ein solcher/eine solche/ein solches* and *ein solche*]
*ein solcher*, *eine solche* and *ein solches* compared to *ein solche*.

[image: Relative frequency of *eine solche/eine solch/ein solche*]
*eine solche* compared to *eine solch* and *ein solche*.

[image: Relative frequency of *ein(e) solch/ein solche*]
Comparison of *eine solch* and *ein solch* (used before adjectives) to *ein solche*.

The adjective-preceding *ein(e) solch* are about ten times as frequent as *ein solche* but they are all minor compared to *eine solche* (the correct form for feminine nouns) – and even the masculine and neuter versions *ein solcher/ein solches* – which is 400 times as common as *ein solche* in the Google Books corpus.

Had the search on your site automatically allowed for variations (e.g. by noting that *such a* may be corresponding to both *ein solche* and *eine solche* in German texts), you would have received a number of correct examples intermingled with the odd incorrect ones. But by searching strictly for an incorrect combination, you would only get incorrect sentences returned.

I will leave the part of the original answer that deals with how the examples are wrong below the horizontal line but note that my criticism of your source no longer applies; instead, the original list may be considered an example of *shit in – shit out.*

---

The source claims to take its examples from ‘millions of previously translated texts: *movie dialogs, official documents, websites, newspapers*’. However, I don’t believe them. Let me go through the first couple of examples:

> *Das impliziert gleichzeitig, daß so ein neues Abkommen auch ein solche Menschenrechtsklausel enthalten muß.

*Klausel* is feminine and so is *Menschenrechtsklausel* so the article must be *eine* giving *eine solche*. Using that would give a correct sentence.

> *Es ist einfach ein solche starkes Medium.

Here, *Medium* is neuter (so *ein* is correct) but nobody would use *solche* hier: it should be *ein solch starkes Medium*.

> *Mit der neuen Regel n+2 verfügen wir jetzt über ein solche, und sie beginnt bereits positive Auswirkungen zu zeitigen.

I have difficulty trying to understand the context the sentence is supposedly creating. If the *solche* is supposed to refer to *Regel,* (feminine) then it would need to be *eine solche* which is reinforced by *sie* in the second half of the sentence. However, the sentence as a whole still wouldn’t make sense which could be due to lacking context.

> *Verfahren nach Anspruch 5 oder 6, wobei die verwendete, das Vernetzungsmittel enthaltende Lösung (C') ein solche ist, bei der das Gewichtsverhältnis von Vernetzungsmittel (C) zu Verdünnungsmittel (Vernetzungsmittel (C)/Verdünnungsmittel) 1/3 bis 1/30 ist.

If this sentence was actually published, it was never proofread. It makes sense, but it is as complicated as humanly possible and could easily be rephrased to something much simples. And since *solche* is referring to *eine Lösung* which again is feminine it must be *eine solche*.

> *Ein solche Geschenk geht nicht verloren und wird nicht vergessen!

It is *das Geschenk* (neuter) and therefore the only correct form is *ein solches Geschenk*.

I skipped over the other examples; I only additionally selected the one about the present to show that not all sentences are wrong in the same way and to display an additional type of error. However, reading them individually, *not a single supposed example would be considered correct German.*

Comment: Mistakes happen.  They have 62 exact hits for “ein solche” and 21709 for “ene solche”.

Comment: @CarstenS Oh, so they actually did a plaintext search for *ein solche* ignoring all other forms? *That* makes much more sense (and may save the source).

Comment: @Jan Thank you very much. Your detailed explanation really helps. There are limited resources that explain the usage of "solch-" in English and I am not able to tell whether it is correct or wrong examples given that I don't understand the topic very well myself. This examples do not match my understanding hence I was confused and had to ask it here.

Comment: @Jan, or they report the “best” results on top.

Comment: @CarstenS Or that. In any case, I have added a ‘new answer’ to the top and only left the bit where I go through why the examples are wrong.

Comment: @Sharon Please also see the edited version of the answer which points out that mistakes happen but are orders of magnitude rarer than correct sentences.

Answer (score 2):

To get back to the actual topic (the correct use of "ein/e solch/e"), I think a collection of correct (well-formed) sentences (with certificate of provenience, so to say) could help:

> Einen solchen Satz sollte man zweimal lesen.
>
> Im Internet steht auch viel falsches. Solch ein Unglück!
>
> Mit solch einer Beispielsammlung kann man sich ein besseres Bild machen.
>
> Mit einer solchen Beispielsammlung kann man gut arbeiten.
>
> Solche eine Sammlung von falschen Sätzen habe ich noch selten gesehen.
>
> Ein solcher Hund ist einfach zu träge, eine Katze zu jagen.
>
> Eine solche Katze ist einfach zu träge, eine Maus zu fangen.
>
> Ein solches Eichhörnchen könnte glatt als Katze durchgehen.
>
> Das Internet ist solch eine nützliche Sache, aber man muss immer gewahr sein, dass dort auch Unsinn verbreitet wird.
>
> Das Internet ist eine solch nützliche Sache...
>
> Solch ein Stroch!
>
> Eines solchen Strolches Bubenstücke würden einen schönen Erzählungsband ergeben.

Comment: Im fünften Beispiel ist dir was durchgerutscht: 'Solche eine Sammlung...' - entweder 'solch eine' oder 'eine solche. Übrigens sagt man umgangssprachlich inzwischen meist 'so' statt 'solch', jedenfalls in meiner Gegend (Westdeutschland): _So ein dolles Ding aber auch!_